# Conan.io and header-only library

Tags: cmake, conan

I'm trying to create a conan package from existing header-only library. It's not your textbook example with `include` folder - structure looks as follows:

```
public/SomeHeader.hpp
public/CHeader.h
public/anotherFolder/AnotherHeader.hpp
```

Here is my **conanfile.py** based on [Documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/header_only.html#how-to-package-header-only-libraries) and some other [things](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/4212).

```
from conans import ConanFile

class MyLibConan(ConanFile):
    name = "MyLib"
    version = "1.0"

def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.includedirs = ["public", "public/anotherFolder"]

def package(self):
    self.copy("*.hpp", dst="public", src="public", keep_path=False)
    self.copy("*.h", dst="public", src="public", keep_path=False)
```

Should I use self.copy in package() method or cpp_info.includedirs? What's the difference?

I export package like this, no errors so far

```
 export . demo/test
```

Then in my main project I have **conanfile.txt** as follows:

```
 [requires]
 MyLib/1.0@demo/test

 [generators]
 cmake
```

My **CMakeLists.txt** previously simply linked exec to MyLib (INTERFACE library)

```
include_directories(MyLibFolder)
add_executable(someTarget ...)
target_link_libraries(someTarget MyLib)
```

Now it looks like this:

```
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()
...
target_link_libraries(someTarget ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

After compiling project

```
mkdir build && cd build
conan install ..
cmake .. -G Ninja
cmake --build .
```

I get errors... :(

```
fatal error: anotherFolder/AnotherHeader.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <anotherFolder/AnotherHeader.hpp>
```

I'm super fresh to conan and I cannot for the love of god grasp how to structure conanfile.py. I've tried many different combinations but without much success

Thanks in advance,

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some answers for your case:

> Should I use self.copy in package() method or cpp_info.includedirs? What's the difference?

In your case, [self.copy](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#package) is the better option. By default, [includedirs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#cpp-info) is defined as `["include"]`, and we usually append other folder only when the package installation doesn't follow the correct folder structure as expected.

> Here is my conanfile.py based on Documentation and some other things.

Your example is missing a very important attribute: [exports_sources](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#exports-sources), without it, Conan won't copy your header files when running conan [export](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/export.html) command. So, your recipe should looks like:

```py
from conans import ConanFile

class MyLibConan(ConanFile):
    name = "MyLib"
    version = "1.0"
    exports_sources = ["public/*"]
    no_copy_sources = True

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.hpp", dst="include", src="public")
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="public")
```

And your conan export will have the listed files:

```
$ conan export . demo/test
Exporting package recipe
MyLib/1.0@demo/test exports_sources: Copied 1 '.h' file: CHeader.h
MyLib/1.0@demo/test exports_sources: Copied 2 '.hpp' files: Someheader.hpp, AnotherHeader.hpp
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: A new conanfile.py version was exported
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Folder: /home/uilian/.conan/data/MyLib/1.0/demo/test/export
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Using the exported files summary hash as the recipe revision: f367d0a701a867835b7ac612b90b3d1c 
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Exported revision: f367d0a701a867835b7ac612b90b3d1c
```

But you still don't have a Conan package, you will need to run `conan install MyLib/1.0@demo/test --build=MyLib`. Instead of running 2-steps, you can use a better command for creating packages, conan [create](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/create.html):

```
$ conan create . demo/test
Exporting package recipe
MyLib/1.0@demo/test exports_sources: Copied 1 '.h' file: CHeader.h
MyLib/1.0@demo/test exports_sources: Copied 2 '.hpp' files: Someheader.hpp, AnotherHeader.hpp
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: A new conanfile.py version was exported
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Folder: /home/conan/.conan/data/MyLib/1.0/demo/test/export
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Exported revision: f367d0a701a867835b7ac612b90b3d1c
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
compiler.version=9
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Forced build from source
Installing package: MyLib/1.0@demo/test
Requirements
    MyLib/1.0@demo/test from local cache - Cache
Packages
    MyLib/1.0@demo/test:5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9 - Build

Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Configuring sources in /home/conan/.conan/data/MyLib/1.0/demo/test/source
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Copying sources to build folder
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Building your package in /home/conan/.conan/data/MyLib/1.0/demo/test/build/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Calling build()
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: WARN: This conanfile has no build step
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Package '5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9' built
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Build folder /home/conan/.conan/data/MyLib/1.0/demo/test/build/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Generated conaninfo.txt
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Generated conanbuildinfo.txt
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Generating the package
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Package folder /home/conan/.conan/data/MyLib/1.0/demo/test/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Calling package()
MyLib/1.0@demo/test package(): Packaged 2 '.hpp' files: Someheader.hpp, AnotherHeader.hpp
MyLib/1.0@demo/test package(): Packaged 1 '.h' file: CHeader.h
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Package '5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9' created
MyLib/1.0@demo/test: Created package revision d1a54d50f9ded97d33be080f4a1ef606
```

Now you have much more output, because Conan is not only exporting, but also building and packaging your package. The build part is a lie actually, because we omitted [build()](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#build).

> I get errors... :(
>
> fatal error: anotherFolder/AnotherHeader.hpp: No such file or directory
> #include <anotherFolder/AnotherHeader.hpp>

Because of this line:

```py
self.copy("*.hpp", dst="public", src="public", keep_path=False)
```

You will have it in your package:

```
$ ls -R public/
public/:
AnotherHeader.hpp  CHeader.h  Someheader.hpp
```

As you set `keep_path=False`, you told to Conan to copy all *.h files and save into public/ folder, but don't keep the original path AnotherFolder/

However, let's a look on the new implementation:

```py
self.copy("*.hpp", dst="include", src="public")
self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="public")
```

Now are keeping the path, using include/ as folder. Why? include/ is the common name used for header files, just like src/ is for source files like .c and .cpp. Try to keep such pattern.

```
$ ls -R include/
include/:
CHeader.h  Someheader.hpp  anotherFolder

include/anotherFolder:
AnotherHeader.hpp
```

Now we can see the header folder is still there and your error won't happen again.

Regards.